# kafka broker Bad file descriptor Exceptions

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-aks, ioexception

i have a IOException on kafka-broker

- kafka-broker on AKS self-installation.
- AKS pvc storage is StorageV2 (General Purpose V2)
- Azure storage
- 3 brokers 1 zookeeper(planning 2 more)
- logs and data path is `/mnt` (not `/tmp`)
- kafka broker version is apache kafka_2.13-3.3.2
- not using kafka-connect or streams
- only using consumer and producer
- no kerberos and any other auth(including ssl)

its only one broker have problem.
other 2 brokers are fine

when i ask to Azure support they said no issues with the storage and also availability was 100%.
They suggested that the problem may be related to Kafka's concurrency issue.

so what can i do or how to search?

```
############################# Server Basics #############################
broker.id=2

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
listeners=...
advertised.listeners=...
listener.security.protocol.map=...
inter.broker.listener.name=...

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
############################# Log Basics #############################
log.dirs=/mnt/kafka-logs/
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=3
delete.topic.enable=true
allow.auto.create.topics=false
offset.retention.minutes=4320
############################# Log Flush Policy #############################


############################# Log Retention Policy #############################
log.retention.hours=48
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
############################# Zookeeper #############################
zookeeper.connect=zk-cluster.zookeeper4kafka.svc.cluster.local:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

```
[2023-04-30 16:19:11,582] ERROR Error while reading checkpoint file /mnt/kafka-logs/cleaner-offset-checkpoint (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/kafka-logs/cleaner-offset-checkpoint: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.common.CheckpointFile.read(CheckpointFile.java:104)
    at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFileWithFailureHandler.read(CheckpointFileWithFailureHandler.scala:48)
    at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.read(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:70)
    at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager.$anonfun$allCleanerCheckpoints$2(LogCleanerManager.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.nextCur(Iterator.scala:587)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,901] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Stopping serving replicas in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,906] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,907] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,919] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Broker 2 stopped fetcher for partitions topic_partitions_names and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory /mnt/kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,919] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-04-30 16:19:37,928] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /mnt/kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

```
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,548] INFO [LocalLog partition=__consumer_offsets-31, dir=/mnt/kafka-logs] Rolled new log segment at offset 43468272 in 142 ms. (kafka.log.LocalLog)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,602] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=__consumer_offsets-31] Wrote producer snapshot at offset 43468272 with 0 producer ids in 20 ms. (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,620] ERROR Error while flushing log for __consumer_offsets-31 in dir /mnt/kafka-logs with offset 43468272 (exclusive) and recovery point 43468272 (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force(Unknown Source)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$flush$1(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.flush(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.$anonfun$flush$1(LogSegment.scala:469)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.flush(LogSegment.scala:467)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,621] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Stopping serving replicas in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,621] ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'flush-log' (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while flushing log for __consumer_offsets-31 in dir /mnt/kafka-logs with offset 43468272 (exclusive) and recovery point 43468272
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force(Unknown Source)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$flush$1(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.flush(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.$anonfun$flush$1(LogSegment.scala:469)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.flush(LogSegment.scala:467)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,703] ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Error while processing data for partition __consumer_offsets-31 at offset 43468272 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: The log dir /mnt/kafka-logs is already offline due to a previous IO exception.
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,704] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Partition __consumer_offsets-31 marked as failed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,704] ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Error while processing data for partition topic-name-1 at offset 1449760 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: The log dir /mnt/kafka-logs is already offline due to a previous IO exception.
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,704] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Partition topic-name-1 marked as failed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,705] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names...) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,706] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names....) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,720] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Broker 2 stopped fetcher for partitions topic_partitions_names... and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory /mnt/kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,720] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-04-30 19:47:17,722] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /mnt/kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

```
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,644] INFO [LocalLog partition=topic-name-0, dir=/mnt/kafka-logs] Rolled new log segment at offset 513743 in 155 ms. (kafka.log.LocalLog)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,704] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=topic-name-0] Wrote producer snapshot at offset 513743 with 0 producer ids in 24 ms. (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,715] ERROR Error while flushing log for topic-name-0 in dir /mnt/kafka-logs with offset 513743 (exclusive) and recovery point 513743 (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force(Unknown Source)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$flush$1(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.flush(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.$anonfun$flush$1(LogSegment.scala:469)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,716] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Stopping serving replicas in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,716] ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'flush-log' (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while flushing log for topic-name-0 in dir /mnt/kafka-logs with offset 513743 (exclusive) and recovery point 513743
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.force(Unknown Source)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$flush$1(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.flush(AbstractIndex.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.$anonfun$flush$1(LogSegment.scala:469)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.flush(LogSegment.scala:467)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,720] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,721] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions HashSet(topic_partitions_names) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,733] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=2] Broker 2 stopped fetcher for partitions topic_partitions_names and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory /mnt/kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,733] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir /mnt/kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-05-03 01:24:09,743] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /mnt/kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

i tried

- re-boot the broker
- re installing the broker
- kafka-broker and zookeeper clear and re setting
- change data and log path /tmp to /mnt

If you need any additional information, please let me know.